# Expectation value as commutation criterion

Tags: quantum-mechanics

One can show using Schrodinger equation that 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \langle\Psi(t)|\hat{A}|\Psi(t)\rangle = \frac{i}{\hbar}\langle\Psi(t)|[\hat{H}, \hat{A}]|\Psi(t)\rangle$$
where $\hat{A}$ is any time-independent operator. From this we have
$$[\hat{H}, \hat{A}] = 0 \Rightarrow \langle\Psi(t)|\hat{A}|\Psi(t)\rangle = Const.$$
I ask the opposite question: Lets say I chose some initial state $|\Psi_0\rangle$ (not any) which is not an eigenstate of $\hat{H}$ and for which 
$$\langle\Psi(t)|\hat{A}|\Psi(t)\rangle = Const.$$
Does this implies that 
$$[\hat{H}, \hat{A}] = 0 ?$$

This is how we would start:
$$\langle\Psi_0| e^{it\hat{H}} \hat{A} e^{-it\hat{H}}|\Psi_0 \rangle = \sum\limits_{k}|\alpha_k|^2 \langle k | \hat{A} |k\rangle + \sum\limits_{k,l,\\k\ne l}\alpha_k^* \alpha_l \langle k | \hat{A} |l\rangle e^{-it(k-l)}$$
where $|\Psi_0\rangle = \sum\limits_k \alpha_k |k\rangle$ is the decomposition of the state in the eigenbasis of $\hat{H}$.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. What about the new question (see edit)?

Comment: If $|\Psi_{0}\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat{H}$, $\langle\Psi(t)|\hat{A}|\Psi(t)\rangle$ for an arbitrary operator $\hat{A}$ is constant.

Comment: I added a little assumption to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the case. For a counterexample, consider a particle on a sphere, with the operator algebra
$$
[J_i,J_j]=i\varepsilon_{ijk}J_k,
$$
and more particularly the evolution of the state $|\psi⟩=|0,0⟩$ (i.e. $l=0$, $m=0$) under the hamiltonian $H=J_z$ (i.e. $|\psi(t)⟩\equiv|0,0⟩$ for all time). This conserves the expectation value
$$
⟨\psi(t)|J_x|\psi(t)⟩\equiv 0,
$$
without $A=J_x$ and $H=J_z$ commuting.

---

On the other hand, if you know that $⟨\psi(t)|A|\psi(t)⟩$ is constant for **all** initial conditions $|\psi(0)⟩$, then it follows from the identities
\begin{align}
\frac{⟨\psi(t)|+⟨\phi(t)|}{\sqrt{2}}A\frac{|\psi(t)⟩+|\phi(t)⟩}{\sqrt{2}}
& =
\frac12⟨\psi(t)|A|\psi(t)⟩
+\frac12⟨\phi(t)|A|\phi(t)⟩
\\ & \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad
+\frac12⟨\phi(t)|A|\psi(t)⟩
+\frac12⟨\psi(t)|A|\phi(t)⟩
\\
\frac{⟨\psi(t)|-i⟨\phi(t)|}{\sqrt{2}}A\frac{|\psi(t)⟩+i|\phi(t)⟩}{\sqrt{2}}
& =
\frac12⟨\psi(t)|A|\psi(t)⟩
+\frac12⟨\phi(t)|A|\phi(t)⟩
\\ & \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad
-i\frac12⟨\phi(t)|A|\psi(t)⟩
+i\frac12⟨\psi(t)|A|\phi(t)⟩
\end{align}
that $⟨\phi(t)|A|\psi(t)⟩$ is also constant for all initial conditions $|\psi(0)⟩$ and $|\phi(0)⟩$. This then means that
\begin{align}
0&=i\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}⟨\phi(t)|A|\psi(t)⟩
=i\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}⟨\phi(0)|e^{iHt}Ae^{-iHt}|\psi(0)⟩
=⟨\phi(0)|[A,H]|\psi(0)⟩
\end{align}
for all states $|\psi(0)⟩$ and $|\phi(0)⟩$, which means that $[A,H]=0$.

---

As a trivial extension of this, you can derive the commutation relation $[A,H]=0$ using only that $⟨\psi(t)|A|\psi(t)⟩$ is constant whenever $|\psi(0)⟩$ is in some set $S$ that spans the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$.

However, that is the weakest condition you can give. If $\operatorname{span}(S)<\mathcal H$ then there are states orthogonal to it for which you cannot say anything. Given $S$ and $\mathcal H$ that satisfy those conditions, and unless $\dim(S^\perp)=1$, there will always be hamiltonians $H$ and operators $A$ for which $A$ is conserved in $S$ but not outside it.

This follows from the fact that in dimension $\geq2$ there are always noncommuting operators; choose $A$ and $H$ to be any two such operators in $S^\perp$ and zero in $S$ and you fulfil the conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that the expectation of $\hat{A}$ is constant. Then we know the expectation of $[\hat{H},\hat{A}]$ must be zero. Your question, then is whether the operator $[\hat{H},\hat{A}]$ itself must be zero. If we are to find a counter-example, we must find a state where the operator $[\hat{H},\hat{A}]$ is non-zero, but nevertheless always has a zero expectation.

A simple case would be when $[\hat{H},\hat{A}] = \hat{P}$, which can be arranged by choosing $\hat{H} = \hat{P}^2 /2m$ and $\hat{A}=\hat{X}$, up to constant factors. Now we must find a state where $[\hat{H},\hat{A}]$ (that is, $\hat{P}$), has zero expectation. This would be a stationary gaussian centered at zero. We know that the evolution of this wavefunction is just for the standard deviation of the gaussian to increase with time, but we will always have $\langle \hat{P} \rangle=0$. So this is a counter-example. So it is not always the case that $[\hat{H},\hat{A}]=0$

Comment: Ok. Now I am fairly convinced that this is in general not true. Maybe there is a way to say whether or not the operator commutes with the Hamiltonian based on some expectation values?

Comment: An operator is zero if and only if its expectation is zero in every state. (This is easiest seen in the basis that diagonalizes the operator.) So if $\hat{A}$ has constant expectation in *every* state (or equivalently, a basis of states), then $[\hat{H},\hat{A}]$ has zero expecation in every state, so it is zero, and so $\hat{A}$  commutes with the hamiltonian.